# how do I fix this glmer error in r: PIRLS loop resulted in NaN value

Tags: r, linear-regression, glm, random-effects, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to run a random effects generalized linear model specifying the family as binomial and a log link to estimate risk ratio (RR) and 95% confidence intervals (CIs). When I run it, I keep getting the error: `Error: PIRLS loop resulted in NaN value`

This is my code:

```
model <- glmer(outcome ~ predictor + (1|random effect variable), data = df, family = binomial(link = "log"))
summary(model, corr = FALSE)
```

How should I correct my code? Also, would it be possible to get the risk ratio by exponentiating the coefficient?

Comment: Log-linked binomial regression isn't as stable as its canonical link -- you could try obtaining starting values from a Poisson model? The error may well have to do with some other issues/overspecification in your model or data, but you haven't provided any details. Either way, some log-binomial models simply *don't* *converge*.

Comment: You can see that there are [lots of similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=PIRLS+loop+resulted+in+NaN+value). We definitely can't answer this without a [mcve] ...